# How to load a URL with iFrame in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, iframe, ionic2, tabview

I wanted to load an URL with Iframe in ionic project. Please have a look at the below sample.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tab-samples

I have written my code in home.ts file.

How can I embedded an URL inside a tabVIew.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to display github.com, which gives the following error :

```
Refused to display 'https://github.com/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
```

This error is displaying due to GitHub's Content Security Policy of not allowing it's view to be displayed within an iframe

If you try with something else, like `https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html`, your code works well. Dependings on which sites you want to display, you should use the [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) ionic native plugin.

Comment: Thanks @saperlipopette, Now I have few questions. Will I be able to load google.com? Do I need to use “embed” in every url?? I am able to load an youtube video with use of “embed”

Comment: google.com also disallows to be embedded in iframes. But youtube allows you to embed videos in iframes